# Simple kotlin example prints kotlin.Unit when printing infix function outcome

Tags: kotlin

I have the following really simple kotlin code to demo infix function
    package com.lopushen.demo.presentation

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Hello " x_x "world")
}


infix fun String.x_x(s: String) {
    println("$this x_x $s x_x")
}
```

And the expected outcome is

```
Hello  x_x world x_x
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Actual outcome below, what causes the program to print kotlin.Unit?

```
 Hello  x_x world x_x
 kotlin.Unit
 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two print statements in your program. The one inside the `x_x` function prints the "Hello world" string, and the one in `main` prints the return value of the `x_x` function. The function doesn't have any `return` statements or a declared return type, so Kotlin infers `Unit` as its return type. The `Unit` type has a single value, `kotlin.Unit`, which is what your program prints.

Comment: Got it, the return type of infix function was not clear for me, assumed that is a String (the same as the receiver). So, this is where Unit comes from. Thanks!